# How calculate in python a history of x,y data to calculate movement?

Tags: python, list

Hello im trying to calculate if an object is stopped or in movement.

In my code I have a list for x, y coordinates like a history.

```
history = [[12,30],[15,30],[25,30],[35,30],[45,30],[50,32],[50,33],[51,32]]
```

Id like to calculate in a history if this object is stopped or in movement.
If I take the distance from last two coordinates I will have a low value that can return for me that this object is stopped.

But id like to get more data like the last 10 information but if i don't have the 10 items in my list I will get all list.

And after that i want calculate the movement distance for each point in a median.

My actual function for distance:

```
def calculateDistance(x1,y1,x2,y2):  
    dist = math.sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)  
    return dist
```

any one can help me ?

Comment: What help are you exactly looking for?

Comment: If you want a way to look back through the last n pieces of data, perhaps a Queue would be a good place to start: https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your position history was sampled at regular intervals you can group the positions by streaks of "closeness" using zip and list enumerations. With these groups of "stillness" you can select the periods of time where a pause of a minimal duration occurred.

*Note that this only requires comparing distances so you don't need to use the square root.*

```
history = [[12,30],[15,30],[25,30],[35,30],[45,30],[50,32],[50,33],[51,32]]

minDist = 5 # this is your distance threshold to determine if a movement occurred
minTime = 3 # stillness time expressed in number of position samples

dists  = ( (ax-bx)**2+(ay-by)**2 for (ax,ay),(bx,by) in zip(history,history[1:]) ) # distance to neighbour
moves  = [ i for i,d in enumerate(dists,1) if d>minDist**2 ]                       # positions where movement occurred
pauses = [ history[s:e] for s,e in zip([0]+moves,moves+[len(history)]) ]           # groups of "stillness"
```

output:

```
for pause in pauses:
    if len(pause) >= minTime:   # check stayed sill for a minimum amount of time
        print(pause[0],len(pause))

# [50, 32] 3
```

*You could refine this by checking if all points in the group are within 1/2 distance from the center (averageX,averageY) and break down the group further based on that (using the same technique if needed)*

Answer (score 0):

you can calculate all the distance between two consecutive values.

```
def calculateDistance(x1,y1,x2,y2):  
    dist = math.sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)  
    return dist

history = [[12,30],[15,30],[25,30],[35,30],[45,30],[50,32],[50,33],[51,32]]
distanceHistory = []
for index in range(0,len(history)):
    distance = calculateDistance(history[idx][0],history[idx][1], history[idx+1][0],history[idx+1][1])
    distanceHistory.append(distance)
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering here as I can't comment yet. For the first question: with only a pair of coordinates you won't be able to easily identify whether the player/object is moving or stopped. You could add a third variable, time. Between two past moves you'd be able to tell for how long the object stood still or how long the move took. If you add a check every x time period, you'd have even more accuracy and you'd know surely if they stood still or not.